# CMS Database Video Storage Table Design

Tags: mysql, sql

Im currently designing the video table for a CMS Im working on and Im a little stumped as to how I should set it up. I need the table to store the following information:

- content_id: a FK referencing the main content table
- The file location for 6 versions: 240p, 480p, and 1080p each in 2 codecs
- The availability of each of the video qualities
- The status of each of the video qualities (Whether they are done being transcoded or not)

So far What I have looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_content_video (
    con_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vid_length INT NOT NULL,
    flv_1080_file_loc VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    flv_480_file_loc VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    flv_240_file_loc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    vp8_1080_file_loc VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    vp8_480_file_loc VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    vp8_240_file_loc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (con_id) REFERENCES tbl_content (con_id)
);
```

Im still uncertain on the best solution for storing the available qualities and their availability status any thoughts are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason for storing the individual file locations. Most of that is going to be highly repetitive pathing data. Instead, keep the paths in a separate table or hard-coded into a config file, and simply use those paths plus the id of the video (`con_it`?) to build a path pointing at the appropriate version of the video.

As for the status stuff, keep a field for each video type you suport, and figure out some values to put in there. 0 - not available, 1 - transcoding, 2- error, 3- good to go, etc...